# Axios returning empty array before returning the data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, api, axios

I have a simple react app which pulls data from an API and prints it to the console.
I'm using Axios to get the values from API.
Here is the API: https://mobile-tha-server-8ba57.firebaseapp.com/walmartproducts/1/20

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Products extends Component {
    state = {
        MetaProducts: []
    }
    async componentDidMount(){
        const res = await axios.get('https://mobile-tha-server-8ba57.firebaseapp.com/walmartproducts/1/20')
        this.setState({ MetaProducts: res.data.products});
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.state.MetaProducts);
        return(
            <div>
                Products
            </div>

        )
    }
}


export default Products;
```

**But Axios, first returns an empty array and then returns the array with data.**

**console:** 
Products.js:14 [] 
Products.js:14 (20) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the asynchronous behaviour of the react life cycles . Your render is called before the completion of your axios request and `this.state.Metaproducts` was never updated inside render as it was already rendered before your request . **You can wait for the callback from the axios and then update the state only after that and make sure to render the product after the completion of ajax**.

I have added one more state variable `init` , and set that as true after getting response from server . By default `init` will be false and then you can show the "loading message " .

Hope it will help you

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Products extends Component {
  state = {
    MetaProducts: [],
    init:0,
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
   await axios.get('https://mobile-tha-server-8ba57.firebaseapp.com/walmartproducts/1/20').then(res => {
      this.setState({ MetaProducts: res.data.products, init:1 });
    });
  }

  renderProduct() {
    return <ul>
    {this.state.MetaProducts.map(p =>
      <li>
        {p.productName}
      </li>
    )};
    </ul>;
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.init ? <div>{this.renderProduct()}</div> : <div>loading...</div>;
   }
}



export default Products;
```

Comment: That's really helpful, thank you. I was also trying to figure out how I can map out the objects. And btw, you haven't declared "res"

Answer (score 3):

This is because in React componentDidMount is called after the render method.

Check the React lifecycle methods here https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#mounting.

It is logging the empty array first which is the default state and then whatever was returned by the axios api call.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean empty array on the console? Sure. It will print empty array. You have to take a look at react lifecycle. `Render` will run first, then the next is `componentDidMount`. Because you initiate the `MetaProducts` as an empty arrray, thats why it will print and empty array first.